# Simple Modal autoresize when window size changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

I have a problem with the Simple Modal (Eric Martin) modal window.

I have a window that needs a scrollbar.  I have found the having autoResize set to true correctly sets the scrollbars when the browser window is shrunk down.

However if I then resize the browser window large again, the modal window stays at the shrunk size.

If I have autoResize turned off and include the following code

```
$(window).resize(function() {
$("#simplemodal-container").css("height","auto");
 $(window).trigger('resize.simplemodal');  
});
```

then the resize works correctly.  However I need autoResize to be turned on in order to get the scrollbars to appear when the browser window is shrunk down.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have managed to answer my own question.  If I define the modal window with the minHeight property set then the modal window will naturally expand back to the correct size when the browser window is re-expanded.

Doing this I don't even need the resize function mentioned above.